# how to communicate between two listfragments in a viewpager from a parent fragmentactivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

Basically I have a **Fragment activity** which holds two **ListFragments** and i use **ViewPager** to swipe between them.In one fragment when i long click on a listItem and select Add Phrase, it updates the database of the other listFragment but never immediately refreshes until i close the app and reopen it. I tried using the official android way of communicating between fragment, using interface in the listFragment and a callback method http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. This is supposed to call the method that fills the data in the second ListFragment but i always get a nullPionterException. Please help me

**This is the first ListFragment (BoardActivity.java, only the portion that adds the interface)**

```
//container activity must implement this interface
public interface OnAddPhraseListener {
    public void onAddPhrase(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);

    //make sure that the container activity has implemented the callback interface
    try{
        mAddPhraseCallback = (OnAddPhraseListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){

    }
}
```

**This is the second ListFragment (PhrasesActivity.java, portion that fills d ListView with data)**

```
public void fillData(){
    try {
        mDbHelper = new PhrasesDbAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity()).open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(tag, "Couldnt open mDbHelper to fill Data");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cursor phraseCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPhrases();
    String [] from = new String[]{PhrasesDbAdapter.KEY_PHRASE};
    int [] to = new int []{R.id.phraseText};
    SimpleCursorAdapter phrases = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.phrases_row, phraseCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(phrases);
}
```

This is the **MainLayoutActivity** that holds the viewpager with **BoardActivity** and **PhrasesActivity**

```
public class MainLayoutActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnAddPhraseListener {

    public ViewPager mViewPager;
    public ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    public com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar mActionBar;
    public Tab tab;
    ComponentName service;
    final String CLIP_CHANGED = "clipboard.clipchanged";
    final String tag = "Clipboard";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        setUpView();
        setTab();

        service = startService(new Intent(this, ClipboardService.class));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClipboardPrefereneActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_about:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void setUpView(){
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private void setTab(){
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
        };

        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Board").setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Phrases").setTabListener(tabListener);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAddPhrase(String text) {
        Log.d(tag, "On Add Phrase callback >>>>>>>>>>>>");
        PhrasesActivity phrasesActivity = (PhrasesActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tab_phrases);

        if(phrasesActivity != null){
            Log.e(tag, "Got Phrases Activity to fill Data");
            phrasesActivity.fillData();
        }
        else{
            Log.e(tag, "Couldnt get Phrases Activity to fill Data");

        }
    }
}
```

The app always gets to the Log message
`Log.e(tag, "Couldnt get Phrases Activity to fill Data");`

Again i read about LocalBraodcastManager can i do the refresh with this? is it a better way? http://getpocket.com/a/read/156004495

Comment: Do not call your Fragments as Activities. It's so ambiguious! Your BoardActivity and PhrasesActivity are fragments, aren't they?

Comment: What is `R.id.tab_phrases`? There is it defined? Post related XMLs too.

Comment: its great u guys responded so quickly thanks. The named Activites are just my identifiers i know its ambiguious i'll change it.

Comment: R.id.tab_phrases is the id of the linear layout which defines the PhrasesActivity. But thanks i'v found a solution. I found that the viewpager uses a format for getting its fragments which is: android:switcher:yourviewpagerid:positionoffragment

Comment: so i used   `PhrasesActivity phrasesActivity = (PhrasesActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":1");` R.id.pager is d id of my viewPager and it works !!!

Comment: BTW, there is awesome library from Square named Otto. It's an event bus dedicated to simplify application components interaction (e.g. Fragment <-> Activity). Your code will be cleaner and more readable without all this "implement a bunch of interfaces" stuff. I can post simple steps to migrate your code to Otto, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do not findFragmentByTag in ViewPager scenario as the tag is not obtainable for their own reason. Use LocalBroadcastManager instead for communicating between fragments.